# Destructuring object with Typescript

Tags: typescript, express

I have the following code however it gives me error. I'm not sure what's the correct way to do this. The error says

```
Type 'CookieSessionObject | null | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ token: string; refreshToken: string; }'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ token: string; refreshToken: string; }'
```

```js
...
  namespace CookieSessionInterfaces {
    interface CookieSessionObject {
      token?: string;
      refreshToken?: string;
    }
  }
}

const currentUser = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const { token, refreshToken }: { token: string, refreshToken: string } = req.session;
...
```

Also `req.session?.token` and `req.session?.refreshToken` work.

Comment: req.session might be null or undefined, so you can't destructure any props out of it safely. The `?.` optional chaining *does* deal with null or undefined, that's what it's for. You could also use a *type assertion* if you know for sure it won't be null or undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.session` can be `null` or `undefined`. Hence in your case, you can handle it as:

```
type Tokens  = {
    token?: string, 
    refreshToken?: string
}

const { token, refreshToken }: Tokens = req.session || {token: null, refreshToken: null}
```

else, if `session` is `undefined` or `null`, you can `throw` an exception which you can catch later and handle accordingly.

```
if (!req.session) {
    throw new UnauthorizeException()
}

const { token, refreshToken }: Tokens = req.session
```

`UnauthorizeException` could be your custom exception or you can use some generic exception as well.

If you are implementing callback, you have to call callback instead of throwing exception.